# Best way to add some custom javascript using jquery to a child theme

Tags: jquery, javascript, theme-twenty-ten, child-theme

I use the default TwentyTen theme and I have made a child theme with some CSS adjustments, and that's pretty much it.

Now I'd like to do two things

- Make the theme load the latest jQuery, and to load it using the Google CDN.
- Add a javascript file which would be loaded on every page.

What's the best way to do that? I'm a total WordPress newb, so don't really know my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_jquery');
function register_custom_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script(
        'jquery', 
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js', 
        array(), 
        '1.6.1'
    );

    wp_register_script(
        'my-custom-script', 
        'http://example.com/js/script.js', 
        array(), 
        '1.0'
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_to_page');
function add_js_to_page() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script' );
}
```

Comment: where do I do this?

Comment: In your theme's functions.php

Comment: Aha. Could you just show how you would enqueue a custom script as well? Just want to be sure I get it right...

Comment: I have updated my answer.